# Trigger a c# event from php

Tags: c#, php

I am very new to c# programming and basically I am a PHP developer.In c# application development I want to trigger an event when a user clicks a button or reload a page in PHP. please give me some guidance on this.

Comment: Hi. What has your research shown so far?

Comment: Please elaborate. Share some code, what are you trying to do.

Comment: You could use webapi, but then, it doesn't make sense to mix 2 backend languages...

Comment: actually i want to show desktop notification balloon by c# application which is executing fine when i double clicks on it. ref: http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/   but now i want to trigger the same when i clicks a button on a php page.how can i link this?

Comment: using soap can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your c# assembly is up and running and some client has subscribed to its events when you click the button, you could notify it through a COM interface from your PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.com.php

You will have to look up how to publish a COM interface in a C# assembly and implement that first.

Comment: yes that's correct. let me try with COM interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the information to a text file using php then using FileSystemWatcher class under .Net framework you can be aware when the file is changed. This is not the best but the easiest way.

For FileSystemWatcher class review the document : [FileSystemWatcher.Changed Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks let me check with this :)